# Mapping multiple sources of data with different field names for mongodb and mongoose (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a website that will house a bunch of data from different sources. The sources may have much of the same data (there is some redundancy), but the fields in the json may vary here and there. These sources are from REST API's, all json.

My question is, how can I map these different sources using mongoose schemas? I want it to be as easy as possible, like some kind of table where I just need to add the field name of the new source, and what field it maps to in my database. I am using express/node.

Here's an example of two sources, and my schema spec.

Eg.

First source:

```
{
    "address":"123 abc st"
}
```

Second source:

```
{
    "addr":"123 abc st"
}
```

My Schema:

```
{
    address:{
        type: String,
        required: true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a JSON file to store the mapping, and retrieve it when storing your object.

For example, create a JSON file `mappings.json`:

```
{
  "addr": "address",
  "address": "address"
}
```

Then check in the code if the property corresponds to a mapped property.

```
let mappings = require('mappings.json');
let MyModel = require('models/myModel');

function createNewObjectFromInput (input, callback) {
   let options = {};
   for (let property in input) {
      if (input.hasOwnProperty(property) && mappings[property]) {
        options[mappings[property]] = input[property];
      }
   }
   let newObject = new MyModel(options);
   newObject.save(callback);
}
```

To make things more robust across multiple sources with possible property collisions you could create such a JSON file for each source, or just a separate mapping for each source, like so:

```
{
  "firstSource": { 
    "addr": "address
  },
  "secondSource": {
    "address": "address"
  }
}
```

And just check which source your input data came from.

Answer (score 0):

By using the model.discriminator() method, you could try to create inheritance between your schemas. Check the Mongoose documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to want here is to simply set up a "virtual" field with the "alias" name. This allows you to use different names for the field but these will "re-map" onto the correct name as defined in the schema.

As a complete demonstration:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const addressSchema = new Schema({
  address: { type: String, required: true }
});

// asssign a virtual to the "mapped" name
addressSchema.virtual('addr')
  .get(function() { return this.address })
  .set(function(v) { this.address = v });

const Address = mongoose.model('Adddress', addressSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    // Raw documents don't work as the setter is ignored
    try {
      await Address.insertMany(
        [{ adddress: "123 abc st" },{ addr: "123 abc st" }]
      );
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    // Creating via new works as expected
    let doc = new Address({ addr: "123 abc st" });
    log(doc);

    // Using Array.map over the objects to cast them works fine
    await Address.insertMany(
      [{ address: "123 abc str" },{ addr: "245 abc st" }]
        .map(Address)
    );

    let inserted = await Address.find();
    log({ inserted });

    mongoose.disconnect();

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})();
```

Which demonstrates the expected results:

```
Mongoose: adddresses.remove({}, {})
{ ValidationError: Adddress validation failed: address: Path `address` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:56:24)
    at formatValue (util.js:430:38)
    at inspect (util.js:324:10)
    at format (util.js:191:12)
    at Console.warn (console.js:145:21)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/alias/index.js:37:15
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  errors:
   { address:
      { ValidatorError: Path `address` is required.
    at new ValidatorError (/home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:25:11)
    at validate (/home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:805:13)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:854:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:814:19)
    at /home/neillunn/projects/alias/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1712:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
        message: 'Path `address` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'address',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        '$isValidatorError': true } },
  _message: 'Adddress validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
{
  "_id": "5b110aa571311d0a70cd3c88",
  "address": "123 abc st"
}
Mongoose: adddresses.insertMany([ { _id: 5b110aa571311d0a70cd3c89, address: '123 abc str', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5b110aa571311d0a70cd3c8a, address: '245 abc st', __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: adddresses.find({}, { fields: {} })
{
  "inserted": [
    {
      "_id": "5b110aa571311d0a70cd3c89",
      "address": "123 abc str",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b110aa571311d0a70cd3c8a",
      "address": "245 abc st",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

To walk through that, all that is defined in addition to the `adddress` field in the schema is setting another virtual property on the schema:

```
addressSchema.virtual('addr')
  .get(function() { return this.address })
  .set(function(v) { this.address = v });
```

This should be pretty straightforward as the `get()` function is used to read from `address` whenever you actually ask for `addr` instead, and the `set()` function is of course applied whenever something attempts to supply a value for `addr` and then puts that value into `adddress` instead.

The only catch is that these "virtuals" do not automatically apply "everywhere" you might attempt to use them. They work find with `new Model()`, but they do not automatically apply on either `Model.create()` or `Model.insertMany()`.

For this case the common workaround as shown is when you have a list of raw input documents, "cast" them by running them through the model constructor "first", just as the listing demonstrates:

```
// Using Array.map over the objects to cast them works fine
await Address.insertMany(
  [{ address: "123 abc str" },{ addr: "245 abc st" }]
    .map(Address)
);
```

Then the data will be correctly re-written to `address` in both documents to be inserted and this happens before the `required` validator fires.

An alternate case is to use the `alias` property on the schema:

```
const addressSchema = new Schema({
  address: { type: String, required: true, alias: 'addr' }
});
```

This actually works in exactly the same way without needing to write the complete "virtual" methods. You might consider this a shorter option to doing the same thing, but you probably should be aware that the intended purpose is actually the "reverse" where you were expected to define a "shorter" name in the schema and use the "longer" one for assignments.

Also you can add as many "virtuals" as you want, but you can only use the `alias` assignment "once" within the schema definition. So if you have different data sources which all use different names for what you want stored then doing the longer form is probably the better way.

Both are documented in the Mongoose Schema documentation

- [Virtual getters and setters](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)
- [Alias field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases)

Comment: I am attempting to go the virtuals route, but not having any luck. this is what I have, and I've tried passing a param via set, and then setting the field to its value, but that doesn't seem to work either. I know I'm doing something wrong here. Can you provide more detail on the virtuals method of accomplishing what I want to do?
    `globalMarketCap
    .virtual('market_cap')
    .get(function(){
        return this.get('total_market_cap_usd');
    })
    .set(function(){
        return this.set('total_market_cap_usd');
    });`